# Create Null-able numeric column in Derived column component

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2016, derived-column

I use **SSIS** in **SQL Server 2016**. I have to create a new column in my DataFlow. I use DrivedColumn component to create this new column. In this case I need a nullable numeric column like below image :

[image]

As you can see, I have error in this case.

How can I create null-able numeric in **Derived column component**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the derived column task there are NULL Functions that you can use if you would like to set a value to NULL.
Select the appropriate NULL function that corresponds to the datatype of your column and plug that into your equation.

You can use NULL(DT_CY) if your column is defined as currency.
Example.  ([currencyAmount]>0? [currencyAmount]:NULL(DT_CY)

In the Derived Column task Null Functions can be found here:
[image]